# Определение координат с помощью Google map api

Tags: google-maps-api, координаты

В Яндексе есть [определение координат](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/tools/getlonglat/), а мне надо сделать такой маркер, который можно двигать только на гугл карте. Подскажите, где посмотреть пример реализации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плохо ищете: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html

Comment: Спасибо! работает :)

Comment: лучшее спасибо - это принятый ответ